# Why is my updated object not appearing in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am using draft-js, with React as a text editor and trying to update the content state with a youtube link (which i'll later thread up to an input/on-change event).

But right now the added-in entity map isn't carrying through from the `convertFromRaw` function.

for context - taking a (convertToRaw) object and replacing the .blocks (text) objects, works fine.

But adding an entity in the same way, does not.

[image]

Comment: Draft docs don't show an `EditorState.createContent()` function - did you mean `EditorState.createWithContent()`? https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#createwithcontent

Comment: @DuncanThacker yes, `createWithContent` is correct, updated the Q. This is not the root of the problem though, sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

this page have a very clear instruction on how to create entity,
[link](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-entities)

why convertFromRaw though? it doesn't make sense, did you even look at the document carefully before asking the question, I suggest you to look it up first, then write code.